# Too much spacing in my table rows

Tags: tables, spacing

My problem is that there appears to be a double-spacing between my rows. The spacing is also too much in between the lines of my column headers. I'm very new to LaTex and I don't know how to rectify this.

Here's what I've done (with only a small fraction of the data set):

```
\documentclass[10pt,fullpage]{aastex}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{c c c c c c c c c c c}
%Header for the first page of the table...
\caption{NGC2264 Protostars}\\
\hline \hline \\ [-.8ex]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Name} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{RA} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{DEC} &                   
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean I1} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean I2} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Alpha K2} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Class} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Alpha K8} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Av} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Avg Av}\\ [0.5ex] \hline
    \\ [-.8ex]
\endfirsthead
%Header for the rest of the table's pages...
\multicolumn{1}{c}{{\tablename} \thetable{} -- Continued} \\ [0.5ex]
    \hline \hline \\ [-.8ex]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Name} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{RA} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{DEC} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean I1} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean I2} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Alpha K2} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Class} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Alpha K8} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Av} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Avg Av}\\ [0.5ex] \hline
    \\ [.8ex]
\endhead
\\\hline
\endfoot

%Begin data...
    Mon-000101 & 100.27242 & 9.608597 & 11.082 & 10.034 & 0.39  & I     & 0.39  & 31.1  & 31.1 \\
    Mon-000171 & 100.2923 & 9.52286 & 14.834 & 14.385 & 0.45  & I     & 0.45  & 33.7  & 33.7 \\
    Mon-000174 & 100.27621 & 9.563802 & 11.605 & 10.134 & 0.95  & I     & 1.29  & 30.8  & 30.8 \\
    Mon-000191 & 100.28709 & 9.495832 & 9.231 & 8.105 & 1     & I     & 1.01  & 0     & 0 \\
    \hline
%End data.
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

As a bonus question: How do I get the top of the page 'Table 1::NGC 2264..' to have 'NGC 2264...' under 'Table 1::' rather than beside it?

[image]

Comment: Notice that you are specifying centred cells `{longtable}{ccccccccccc}` and then also centering individual one-column-multicolumn cells with `\multicolumn{1}{c}{<text>}`.  The use of `\multicolumn` is redundant in this case.

Comment: @jon So what would be the best thing to remove to avoid redundancy?

Comment: Oh, well, change `\multicolumn{1}{c}{<text>}` to just `<text>` should do the trick.  It's just a lot of extra typing that can go wrong for no real change in appearance.  Even if you left the braces out of laziness (i.e., `{<text>}`) there'd be no change.

Comment: @jon Thank you. That's good to know. I'm ignorant enough to all of this that I just throw together stuff I see around tutorials, etc. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries.  Just use `\multicolumn{2}{c}{<text>}` when you want to merge two cells and horizontally centre the content (i.e., the `<text>`); or `{3}` or `{4}`, etc. if you want to merge-and-centre 3 or 4 or more cells. Also: `{l}` or `{r}` left- or right-aligns the material.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default [`aastex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/aastex) sets a document that seems double-spaced. This spills over into tabular design as well. You can adjust the height of each row by setting a value to `\arraystretch` that is less than 1. For example, the left image shows the default, while the right image shows an `\arraystretch` of `0.7`:

[image]

You would use (say)

```
\begin{landscape}
  \centering%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7}%
  \begin{longtable}{..}
    % <table content>
  \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Awesome. That will work. As a side question: How would I move "NGC2264 Protostars" underneath, rather than next to "Table 1::"? Thanks again.

Comment: @Matt: That would be a different question (if you can't find it on this site already). You may look into the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) which has a `newline` option.